# I have a few GUI's in MATLAB and I need to view them in different tabs

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabpanel, matlab-guide

I have 3 GUI files created using GUIDE. I need to have a tab Panel where I can view all of them in different tabs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward way to accomplish that. A figure cannot be displayed inside another figure. GUIDE creates figure. You can convert your GUIDE figure to programmatical GUI by using some conversion procedure. There is one official by Mathworks, or other ones on [file exchange](http://mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14340-convert-fig-to-matlab-code). Then, you should place the 3 figures children inside a panel each.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tab object in MATLAB.  You can generate your own by making your own graphical objects: the tab buttons, that users can click to run a function that puts the right "tab" in front using **uistack** to change the order of your graphical objects, always bringing the clicked tab to the front.

But you would do this all in one GUI, in one figure window; you just not to make sure that hold is on in the figure, and you have to give all your plots a handle so that you can manipulate them with uistack.